# Meteor Can't load settings from the json file

Tags: javascript, json, meteor, ecmascript-6

I have created the following `settings.json` file based on [this site](https://medium.com/@SamCorcos/up-and-running-with-meteor-settings-settings-json-3090d4c259ea) with the following content:

```
{
    "azure":{
      "container":"The container to store the data",
      "account":"The account name",
      "key":"The key that is used for authentication"
    }
}
```

I also created a file named `imports/settings/fileUploadSettings.js` that has the following content:

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';

export const FileUploadSettings= {
  'container': Meteor.settings.azure.container,
  'account': Meteor.settings.azure.account,
  'key': Meteor.settings.azure.key
}
```

Afterwards I run it with the command:

```
meteor --settings=./settings.json
```

But when I visit http://localhost:3000 I get the following error:

> TypeError: Meteor.settings.azure is undefined

Comment: Did you try `meteor --settings settings.json`?

Comment: And if you want to access to variables on client, you have to place variables in `public` section

Comment: @none In the end that was the answer. Please submit it bellow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to access to variables on client, you have to place variables in `public` section